# Is there a command to go directly to a package's function index Help page?

Tags: r

Typing `?stats` brings me to a Help page that describes what the `stats` package does. At the bottom of that page there is a link to `Index` that brings me to a page that lists every function that is included in the package.

Is there a command that brings me directly to that list of functions without having to click that link? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A failsafe way of doing what @Khaynes posted is like;

```
help(package=stats, try.all.packages = TRUE)
```

For example; if you try to get help on a package which doesn't have the doc, it refers to a related one.

```
help("bs", try.all.packages = TRUE)
```

Update - As @DuckPyjamas mentioned, this also shows function list for a package that has not yet been attached to the session.

Comment: Thanks, I picked this as the answer because it allows me to look at the function list for a package that has not yet been attached to the session.

Comment: That's great. I have updated the answer with your finding.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
help(package = stats)
```